# Two post methods in one WebApi controller, results in application not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web Api Controller

```
public class ImageUploadController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public string UploadImage(int id)
    {
        return "Value = " + id;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadImage([FromBody] Customer customer)
    {
        string name = customer.company_name;

        string dooda = string.Empty;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool DeleteImage(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            string dooda = string.Empty;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The get and post method for UploadImage work but as soon as I add another post i.e DeleteImage neither of the posts work.

I get a 404 Bad Request for both methods.

In my view I have two buttons, one that calls the upload image and the other that calls delete image as shown here

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnPushMe">Push Me</button><br />
<button id="btnDeleteMe">Delete Me</button>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#btnPushMe').click(function () {

    var apiurl = "http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/UploadImage"

    var customer = { customer_name: "Scott", company_name: "HP" };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(customer),
        url: apiurl,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });

});

$('#btnDeleteMe').click(function () {

    var apiurl = "http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: "2" },
        url: apiurl,
        contentType: "application/json"
    });

});
</script>
```

This is my config

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Again I'm just playing around with Web Api and trying to learn it as I go so if someone can enlighten me in to why/what I'm doing wrong I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Try HttpPut for DeleteImage method?

Comment: @TienDinh tried changing [HttpPost] to [HttpPut] went back to the view and pressed delete and it posted back to UploadImage post not delete image, so I changed POST to PUT within the ajax and still I got a 404 bad request

Answer (score 1):

The route template you are using is a "restful" one that will map to controller actions purely by the HTTP verb. i.e. There is no {action} in the template.

When you add the second post method WebAPI cannot disambiguate the calls.(For example `http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/UploadImage` and `http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage` both match api/{controller}/{id} which also matches both action methods. The action isn't specified in your template url.

Using a template like api/{controller}/{action}/{id} would map the urls you are calling with. Note this is then stepping away from a restful approach; which isn't necessarily wrong.

You might also consider adding specific templates - e.g. api/ImageUpload/UploadImage and explicitly set the action in the defaults.

Or you could use attribute based routing which would let you add an attribute directly to the action method with the desired url. This is often better for non-restful style controllers.

Comment: Ok, I have modified the template you mentioned, now when I click on  Delete me I get 404 not found, but on the upside the other post method is working

Comment: Your passing the id in the body - put it on the URL `http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage/2` or use a [FromBody] to tell WebAPI where to get the id.

Comment: doing this worked http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage/2 for some reason when I used [FromBody] I kept getting the error 404 not found again, can you think of why?

Comment: after some investigation the error was infact moaning about the parameter ID should be able to accept nulls, even though I was passing it in using data { id : 2 } when I made int id to a nullable int it worked, why is it though the Id 2 doesn't get passed in? when I have [FromBody] in my controller  ?

Comment: It's because the body you are sending is an object with an id property, if the body was simply `2` instead of `{ id: "2" }` it would be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.stringify(data), as you are setting the content type as `application/json`.

You could have passed the value as part of the uri like delete/12 or delete?ID=12.

IMHO, Also, you can use HttpDelete for delete verbs instead of put or post, unless delete is not accepted.

HTH

Comment: I've changed it to [HttpDelete] and added the following line  var data = { id: 2 }; and inside the ajax method I've done  data: JSON.stringify(data), which gives me the same error 405 Method Not Allowed this is my complete ajax method $('#btnDeleteMe').click(function () {

        var data = { id: 2 };

        var apiurl = "http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage"

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            url: apiurl,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });

    });

Comment: Try passing as query string parameters  delete image/2 . Also I still see you using post instead of delete in ajax, which is why you still get 405

Comment: That works, but ideally I would like to pass it as the way I showed  in my previous comment that way its consistent through out the application

Comment: Sure, just set method as delete in ajax and set data as ID alone, no need for content type as you are not indeed posting complex objects. 1 property can be passed as such

Comment: I've managed to get it to work, later on down the line we will be adding more parameters so I've decided to implement a model called ImageDetails same set up as the UploadImage shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code please just remove the **contentType: "application/json"**  on ajax method. Then it will automatically lead u to the controller page.

Please get look on the below code

```
$('#btnDeleteMe').click(function () {

var apiurl = "http://localhost:50793/api/ImageUpload/DeleteImage"

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: "2" },
    url: apiurl,

});
```